# Add Prev/Next buttons

Tags: jquery

This is the code of tabs.
I just need add Prev/Next buttons.
How do I do that?
Already tried with jquery ui tabs function but not work.

```
$(function(){
    var first =0;
    var cont =1;
    $('#page-default .component-group:nth-child(4)').each(function(){       
        var newContent = "<div class='produtos'><div class='title'></div><div class='borda'></div><div class='tabs'><ul class='tab-links'>";
        var tabLink ="";
        var tabContent="<div class='tab-content'>";
        $(this).find($('.component')).each(function(){
            if(first==0){
                tabLink += "<li id='tb"+cont+"' class='active'><a class='#tab"+cont+"'>"+$(this).find($('.legend .title')).text()+"</a></li>";
                tabContent += "<div id='tab"+cont+"' class='tab active'>"+$(this).find($('.content')).html()+"</div>";
                first++;
            }
            else{
                tabLink += "<li id='tb"+cont+"'><a class='#tab"+cont+"'>"+$(this).find($('.legend .title')).text()+"</a></li>";
                tabContent += "<div id='tab"+cont+"' class='tab'>"+$(this).find($('.content')).html()+"</div>";
            }
            cont++;
        });
        tabLink += "</ul>";
        tabContent += "</div>";
        newContent += tabLink+" "+tabContent+"</div></div>";
        $(this).html(newContent);
        first=0;
    });
    $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('class');
        $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: <div class="tabs">
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab4" class="tab active">
</div>
<div id="tab5" class="tab">
</div>
<div id="tab6" class="tab">
</div>
</div>
</div>